# Opening one browser from another browser

Tags: javascript

I am running my web application on Firefox. I have hyperlink on one of the page and when I click on it, it opens another application as a new popup. 
But that application is not supported on Firefox. So I want to open it in Internet Explorer, i.e., though I am running the application on Firefox, that particular popup should open in Internet explorer. I am using this to open new window:

```
var win = window.open(url, "NewWindow", strFeatures);
```

Comment: You can't do things like this from a web page, in general.

Comment: Imagine how chaotic the web would be if JavaScript could do things like this! Instead of opening internet explorer, why not opening the regedit!

Comment: If this is an in-house application, [this trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795560/lauch-external-program-in-firefox-or-chrome) might work; if it's a public app, how are you going to deal with Linux or Mac users who don't have IE installed in the first place?

Comment: Also, if you can get your users to install a Firefox add-on (or have an admin install it for them, in an office setting), [that could do the trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754621/how-can-i-open-an-external-app-from-firefox-addon-eg-default-text-editor).

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with just ordinary JavaScript; as Levi notes, if you could, that would be a usability and security nightmare.

That said, there are a couple of ways you could get something like this to work.  For example, [a Firefox add-on can launch external programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754621/how-can-i-open-an-external-app-from-firefox-addon-eg-default-text-editor), so you could write such an add-on to open your app in IE, and ask your users to install it (or have an admin pre-install it for them, if this is e.g. for an in-house app in a managed workplace setting).

Another possibility might be to use a custom URL scheme (like `myapp:`) to link to your application, and [register that URL scheme to be opened in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795560/lauch-external-program-in-firefox-or-chrome) (or, rather, in some kind of a wrapper script that takes the custom URL, converts it to a normal HTTP URL, and opens it in IE).  Again, though, this requires configuring (and, probably, installing a script on) the end-user's computer, so it's probably only suited for office or similar environments.

Note that both of these solutions have security implications that you should keep in mind.  In particular, any add-on or script you use for them should *only* work for specific URLs that point to your app, and should refuse to open any other URLs someone might try to feed it.

In any case, if you're trying to do this for a public website, keep in mind that there's *no way* you can make this work for Linux / Mac users who don't *have* IE to begin with.  And even many Windows users might be reluctant to use IE (not to mention installing an untrusted extension!) without a *very* good reason; after all, there's presumably a reason why they chose to use Firefox (or Chrome or Opera or whatever) in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible and for good reason.  Just think of what someone clever -- arguably -- could do if they could cause various programs to run on your computer because you clicked a link on a website...

This is what you're trying to do...run another native application from clicking a link in a browser.

Why not just use Internet Explorer for everything since it works for the pop up?

Comment: ok tell me how to run exe using javascript ?

Comment: @user4622067 - I'm not sure you read this answer.  What you are asking for is not possible.

Comment: That's a different question altogether and goes off into other areas.  To run an exe using javascript you can create a node.js app that uses the Child Process module to spawn or fork a child process -- which could be an exe.  However, I highly doubt this is the answer you are looking for.  Within the browser -- like what you want to do -- it's not gonna happen.