# How to fire "download from another browser" event from chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download

I'm trying to write a JS/JSX code that enables Chrome call "Download Files" function from another browser. I'm trying to download an excel sheet from a browser, but when I try to call the file from Chrome, it loads for a while then says (Server took too long to respond). The trick here, is that when I take the exact URL and try to download the file through **Edge**, it downloads without any problems.
So, what I am trying to do is to find a way (preferably a code), that will trigger an event (in the context of opening Edge, then taking that URL then downloading the file), all through Chrome.

I've tried running through why Chrome is doing this, as I first suspected that the issue was with the URL, but as I said above, Edge works fine.
I searched online but I couldn't find the good wording for it, since it's a kind of a complex problem. I couldn't find a way to write the code, however.
Unfortunately, I haven't found a similar issue online and I am not sure if "SuperUser" forums were the right place to post this question, since I'm basically asking for code.

I expect that when I click on the download link on Chrome, Edge opens up and downloads the file (or if we are living in Utopia, then Chrome would just download the file; unfortunately I can't give more details about the situation unless asked, because I'm a bit lost here).

~Thank you <3

Comment: Can't be done unless the user has a special browser extension.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29235353/opening-one-browser-from-another-browser

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070744/open-ie-browser-in-firefox-chrome-page

Comment: It's different. Because I wanna start Edge browser when I click on the download URL, and enable Edge to download the file.

Comment: Conceptually it's the same.

Comment: Yes, my bad.
I didn't understand the other question properly at the beginning.