# How to edit this function to make 3 things instead of 2

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser-cache

I use this function with cache to make if the user enter the site for first time in last
x minutes redirect him and if this is the second time press the button i now want to add if this is the third time in last x minutes to do another thing.

```
function getCookie(name) {
  const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
  const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
  if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}

function setLastAccess() {
  const date = new Date();
  const expireMs = 0.5 * 60 * 1000; // number of minutes
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + expireMs);
  document.cookie = `lastAccess=${new Date().getTime()};expires=${date.toUTCString()};path=/`;
}

if (!getCookie('lastAccess')) {
  window.location.href = "http://google.com";
  setLastAccess(); // set your last access at the end
} else {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('button-login').click();
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Add a second cookie with a counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain a counter in `localStorage` whenever user access the site, and update it. Check for the count and if it is 3, run your logic.

You can also store it in `cookie` if it needs to be transferred to server.

```
function getCookie(name) {
  const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
  const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
  if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}

function setLastAccess() {
  const date = new Date();
  const expireMs = 0.5 * 60 * 1000; // number of minutes
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + expireMs);
  document.cookie = `lastAccess=${new Date().getTime()};expires=${date.toUTCString()};path=/`;
}

function numAccess() {
  if(!localStorage.getItem('accessCount')) {
    localStorage.setItem('accessCount', '1');
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem(+localStorage.getItem('accessCount') + 1)
  }
}

if (!getCookie('lastAccess')) {
  window.location.href = "http://google.com";
  setLastAccess(); // set your last access at the end
  numAccess();
} else {
  setTimeout(function() {
    numAccess();
    document.getElementById('button-login').click();
  }, 1000);
}

if(+localStorage.getItem('accessCount') === 3) {
  // Do some stuff
}
```

Comment: thank you but i have one question please can you tell me if the user uses firefox browser how to make him redirected to a specific link on Google Chrome brwoser ?

Comment: @MohamedAshrafFahim I don't think it is possible to do that. We can force users from one browser to other browser. More details  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29235353/opening-one-browser-from-another-browser . You can however add a warning or prompt which tells users to open the link in Chrome.